# Sufficient condition for connectedness

Tags: graph-theory

> Assume a **simple** graph $G$ with degree sequence $d= d(v_1) \geq d(v_2)
>  \geq \dots \geq d(v_n)$ such that for every $k$ with $1 \leq k \leq n
>  - 1 - d(v_1)$ : $\quad$  $d(v_{n - k + 1}) \geq k$. Show that $G$ is **connected**.

### Attempt:

(***Equivalently:*** for every $k$ with $d(v_1) + 2 \leq k \leq n$:$\quad$ $d(v_k) \geq n - k + 1$)

Assume two vetrices $v_i, v_j$ with $i,j \in [2 + d(v_1), n]$. We shall show that there is a path from $v_i$ to $v_j$.

If the edge $(v_i, v_j)$ exists, it's trivial. Assume this edge does not exist.

Then $|N_G(v_i)| \geq n - i + 1$ and $|N_G(v_j)| \geq n - j + 1$, where $N_G(\cdot)$ is the set of all the neighbors of a vertex in $G$.

Now we will assume that $N_G(v_i) \cap N_G(v_j) = \varnothing$ to get a contradiction. If this is the case then:

$$
|N_G(v_i) \cup N_G(v_j)| = |N_G(v_i)| + |N_G(v_j)| \geq 2n - (i+j) + 2 \quad \quad (1)
$$

but since $\{v_i, v_j\} \notin N_G(v_i) \cup N_G(v_j) $:

$$
|N_G(v_i) \cup N_G(v_j)| \leq n - 2 \quad \quad (2)
$$

Do $(1),(2)$ combined obtain the desired contradiction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this does not contain the desired contradiction. Let $i = n, j= n-1$. Then (1) evaluates to $3$, which is not a contradiction to (2).

Hint for the exercise (if you want it): Induction on $j \in \{2, \dots, n\}$, consider the set $N(v_1) \cup \{v_1\}$.